# Issue regarding date column in Excel and PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, ssas, data-warehouse, ssas-tabular

I am currently trying to create a tabular model AWTest on SQL Server Analysis Services using a AdventureWorksDW2014 database. I am running a SQL Server (version 2016) instance on my PC (Windows 10).

I came across on a strange behaviour regarding the date column FullAlterneteDate (SQL data type = date).
In my tabular model (compatibility level 1200), I have included, among others, DimDate and FactInternetSales tables and created appropriate relationship. But, when I try to analyze the data in Excel (version 2016) or PowerBi, the FullAlternateKey is only "partilly" recognized as a date column.

I can insert the date timeline by clicking the Insert timeline option in Analyze Excel ribbon and I can choose the date filters by right-clicking on the column in field list. The things I cannot do are:

1. Add a timeline by right-clicking the column in field list
2. Group/ungroup dates by right-clicking on date field in PivotTable
3. Group ribbon is disabled

I have checked the following:

1. Mark the DimDate as Date table and FullAlternateDate as the date column
2. FullAlternateKey has Date data type formatted as short date (the same as the current culture on my Windows)
3. Deploying model and using it as SSAS data source in Excel

I have tried to access the AdventureWorksDW2014 database directly from Excel, and had no issues with date recognition.

I am interested, has anyone had similar problems or knows how to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, when you submit a question, try to replicate your problem, not just describe, so someone can help you. It is hard to replicate from a description

Comment: Compatibility level 1200 is problematic in many areas. I wouldn't help anyone with any problems with SSAS unless they are at a minimum of at least 1400 (which you can do with SSAS 2016). Don't know if the problem is related to it, but I'm not going back to check.